# Adjusting Scene Scale with BLAM to real world estimation measurement

Tags: scale, measurement, blam

I am remodelling a scene from -presumably- a photo. Using BLAM addon.

I would like to know how to adjust the 3D model in the scene.
To the real world estimated measurement.

As can be seen in the Properties Panel, the z measurement is too small.
According to commonly used real world scale for the counter top board, perhaps there's a way to make the whole model/scene scaled with 30-40 mm thickness of the counter top?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a button in BLAM to do the first part of this.. 'Set line of sight scale pivot'.. but you can do it by hand.

Set the Pivot Center to the camera by <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> putting the 3D cursor there, and selecting '3D Cursor' as the Pivot Center.

Then, selecting all the objects whose dimensions you want to alter, (not including the camera,) with the counter-top active, uniformly scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) all the objects in your scene, until the right dimension appears in the Z of the counter-top. The size of the objects will not change in the (perspective) camera view.

You could also place an Empty at the camera, temporarily parent all the objects you want to scale to the Empty, and scale the Empty. This gives the opportunity for more accurate control.

Swipe and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> copy the Z dimension of the counter-top into your clipboard. Select the empty, swipe all its scale fields, and type the desired dimension into all of them, followed by <kbd>/</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> ( your typed result would be '30/0.17759', if you wanted a 30mm thickness). Then <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> , unparent the objects, keeping their transformations.

It's probably better to apply (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>) the scale of your objects when you're done, to put the new dimensions into the meshes, rather than their object transforms.

EDIT:

Please find the scaled file, with counter-top at about 35mm. Scaling did involve some steps I couldn't include in this answer without seeing the scene: adjusting clipping distances on the camera and in the view.. scaling the camera to make the view practical. The method described still applies, if you need to tweak.

[image]

Comment: thank you. but how to parent all the objects to the Empty?
i am new to blender. i haven't learn about parent things yet.

Comment: In Object Mode, select all the objects, with the Empty last, so it is active, then hit Ctrl-P > 'parent to object'. Un-parenting is Alt-P .. you would want to 'Keep Transformations', in this case.

Comment: got Error parsing message while trying to scale the Empty. Blender v 2.79b.
i'll try the first method you mentioned before the Empty.
Edit: no avail. the meshes went off. and can't be seen from either the camera view or orbit view.

Comment: Works for me.. I'm not familiar with that error.. maybe BLAM is trying to do something at the same time? BLAM itself creates an empty at the camera for some jobs.. make sure you've selected the right one.

Comment: @irwan     Maybe put your file up [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and edit your question to include the link?  This resizing stage doesn't require the actual use of BLAM...

Comment: uploaded the blend file as attachment. sorry, have to learn how to add attachment first. by searching the web.

Comment: @irwan  Please find scaled file attached.

Comment: thank you very much, Robin Betts. that's awesome. how did you do that without making meshes out of scene from cam perspective? or, without having parsing error when using the empty to scale? what blender version are you using? i typed 30/0.17759 in the empty's scaled box and returns error.
would you make a video or gif tutorial somewhere else? thanks very much again, Robin.

Comment: 2.79, of 2018/06/05.. The one _big_  difference I noticed in your file was that the 3D Cursor was not at the camera? That's essential... The parsing thing.. the get-around would be to do it in an external calculator, and cut and paste from there,, It's not awesome for me, unless you can do it for yourself, and understand why it works.Me, I find making/editing gifs and videos a bit tricky on my little laptop atm.. maybe you can show me that!

Comment: Robin Betts
thanks for all of your replies and answers. i've made it. and somewhat understand it a bit better now.
though i still haven't found the ".. a button in BLAM to do the first part of this.. 'Set line of sight scale pivot'.." yet, 
i have found that "active element" as pivot point on the empty (that is also on the camera) works. and it doesn't cause parsing error anymore, afterwards (tried over again to practice).